# Leaflet Loop to create circles for array data

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

I am trying to create a loop to read this line:

```
circles[i] = L.circle([50.895763, -1.150556], {
```

but instead of having the lat, lng hardcoded, get it from the array below:

Here is the code:

```
var circles = [
  {
    "lat": 50.895763,
    "lng": -1.150556
  },
  {
    "lat": 50.895763,
    "lng": -1.148071
  }
];

var arrayLength = circles.length -1;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  circles[i] = L.circle([50.895763, -1.150556], {
  color: "red",
  fillColor: "#f03",
  fillOpacity: 0.5,
  radius: 100
}).addTo(mymap);
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used the variable name `circles` for both the input data and the array of circles, so separating them out you could do this...

```
var circles = [
  {
    "lat": 50.895763,
    "lng": -1.150556
  },
  {
    "lat": 50.895763,
    "lng": -1.148071
  }
];

var circlearray = [];

circles.forEach(function (circle) {
  var onecircle =  L.circle(circle, {
    color: "red",
    fillColor: "#f03",
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 100
    }).addTo(mymap);
  circlearray.push(onecircle);
})
```